# PaintComponent with a Layout Manager

Tags: java, image, swing, layout, paintcomponent

Is it possible to position a BufferedImage that is drawn by the PaintComponent method? For instance, if it is an image drawn in the overridden PaintComponent method, is it possible to use a layout manager (i.e. BoxLayout, BorderLayout, FlowLayout, GridBagConstrains, GridBagLayout) for that? Or do you have to translate the image to a JComponent (i.e. JLabel)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to position a BufferedImage that is drawn by the PaintComponent method?

Yes it is possible. You would get the dimensions of the drawing component in its `paintComponent(...)` method via `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`, and then use those dimensions to position things. Also, the `Graphics#drawImage(...)` method has overloads that simplify this for you.

> For instance, if it is an image drawn in the overridden PaintComponent method, is it possible to use a layout manager (i.e. BoxLayout, BorderLayout, FlowLayout, GridBagConstrains, GridBagLayout) for that?

No, not directly since layout managers are for laying out child components only.

> Or do you have to translate the image to a JComponent (i.e. JLabel)?

You could easily do that -- put your Image in an ImageIcon and that in a JLabel, and position that in a container using whatever nested components and their layout managers that work best.

**Edit 1**
You ask in a comment:

> How do I get the dimensions?

Again, inside of the `paintComponent(...)` method simply call `getSize()` or `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` and you've got your dimensions. Nothing could be easier really.

> And could you provide a snippet of code of your first instance paintComponent(...)?

I would suggest that you go first. Show us some of your code that compiles and runs, and tries to demonstrate your problem, and let's work with that.